# Gnome shell on debian use to much resources

Tags: debian, gnome, intel, amd

I recently install debian 8 on my system and install gnome. But after working for couple of minutes I notice that my battery is discharging very fast. So I check CPU usage and it using half of CPU capacity. I have AMD and intel graphic cards on my Laptop.

Comment: Who is running that gnome-shell instance? I've noticed something similar on my machine and it's being run by `gdm`. In my case, I can simply `sudo killall gnome-shell` and that brings everything back down to normal levels. If that works for you, I'll post an answer.

Comment: does the problem persist with alternate DE such as lxde/lxqt ?

Comment: @terdon I think I did what you said I kill gnome-shell with kill command but everything gone crazy .after force shutdown it won't log in to my system.

Comment: @Vesal75 the command I gave (`sudo killall gnome-shell`) would kill any running instances of `gnome-shell` and do it gently. It wouldn't affect your system, it doesn't touch any system files and wouldn't stop you from logging in to your system. Did you do anything else?

Comment: @terdon I typed kill (the number of gnome-shell)

Comment: Please join me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35976/discussion-on-question-by-vesal75-gnome-shell-on-debian-use-to-much-resources) to debug.