# Problem with gdm on debian

Tags: login, gnome-shell, gdm, gdm3

I wanted to fix one problem and created another. I had a `gnome-shell` process which was [taking up a lot of my CPU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264427/22222). I tried `pkill gnome-shell` and after that I couldn't do anything and was forced to shutdown.

After rebooting, a GUI error message appears:

```
a problem has occurred and the system can't recover please log out and try again
```

I discussed this problem with one of the users of this site who suggested I try the following:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
no job for gdm.services failed. See 'systemctl status gdm.services' and 'journalctl-xn' for details

$ systemctl status gdm.services
gdm.servic- Gnome Display Manager
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/gdm.service; enabled)
Active : inactive (dead)
```

I don't know what I did but when I use

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

it won't show that error but still the same problem exist.

I can succesfully login but It's just one desktop envirement and won't show others. I use this

```
echo /usr/sbin/lightdm | sudo tee /etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

Comment: Do you have automated login or manual? Can you log in at a shell environment (press `CRTL+ALT+F1`) and then use `startx`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) the output of `journalctl -xn`; ii) the contents of your `/var/log/xorg.0.log`; iii) tell us if you have automatic login enabled as suggested by GAD3; iv) the result of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`.

Comment: @Fiximan What do you by a automated login I guess yes. Yes I can.

Comment: @Vesal75 my first guess would be an error in the Xauthority then. I had something similar and could fix it by simply deleting `~/.Xauthority` (for your standard user of course). You get the error due to the automated login. If the automated login is disabled, you should simply see the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

When logout error appear just press (Ctrl+Alt and F1 , F2 or F4 ) and enter your previously used root username password or create another user and after that type:

`nano /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` (use sudo for non root user )

And change it

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=false
```

`AutomaticLogin=root` or user1 (if u create a new user and want to login from it)

To

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
```

`AutomaticLogin=root` or user1

Reboot

Comment: It was 'true' and 'root'. I didn't have to change that file.